# Automatically insert @since tag for all files

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc

I wonder if it is possible to insert automatically `@since` tag in all Java files which don't have it. I am using IDEA.

We have a template

```
/**
 * @author nkuznetsov
 * @since 25.03.14
 */
```

but some people long time ago missed @since so it is

```
/**
 * @author nkuznetsov
 */
```

It should be filled with file creation date from SVN.

Comment: Please reply on my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24787663/2650174)**. If it's not helped for you I just delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [File and Code Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/file-and-code-templates.html)

`File -> Settings -> File and Code Templates` where choose **Class** and customize template as you need.

### Template:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
/**
 * @author ${USER}
 * @since ${DATE}
 */

public class ${NAME} {
}
```

### Result:

```
package com.somepackege.lang.test;

/**
 * @author Mario
 * @since 7/16/14
 */
public class Cool {
}
```

Also check this **[guide](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html)** where you can find more information about **template variables**.